# Can I use regex to find the cheapest price on a product page?

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

I'm trying to build a dynamic script to scrape prices off of my client's website to insert into ads using ad customisers. Some product pages are easy as they only have one price, but in some cases there are several. How would I write a script that uses a regex to match for any prices on the page, and then returns the cheapest one?

Comment: I recommend you read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jul The steps to build that script are longer than can be answered here. What you need to build is a "Spider" for "Crawling" your customers site for certain criteria. Google how to parse an HTML page. Theres no single answer to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex has it's limitations. It'll match for prices, but you'll need a script in order to process the information regex finds for you.

Assuming your question is primarily about finding the cheapest price, here is a script that'll take the variable pageText, scrape it for currency numbers, convert to integers and then grab the lowest number.

```
var pageText = "$65.54, hello there king cupid. $54.32 & of course 
$50. $170,000.54";
var pricesRegex = /(\$[0-9,]+(\.[0-9]{2})?)/g;
var parsedPrices = pageText.match(pricesRegex);
var numbers = [];
parsedPrices.map((price) => {
numbers.push(Number(price.replace(/,/g, '').split("$")[1]));
});
var cheapestPrice = Math.min.apply(null, numbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with regex, at least not without going completely insane. Regex is a tool that matches characters - numbers, letters and so on. It does not know anything about the meaning of the characters. Typically, you can use it to extract some portion of the text from another text, but to perform numerical comparison you need to convert the text to a number, such as using a proper programming language.